# Set Selenium proxy programmatically

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

In my automation project I need to set proxy server. I tried with system variable settings and profile setting for firefox browser. But those technique does not work for me. Please any one help me in this regard.

Note: I also tried with executing shell command using java but I got stuck when password is asked.

Comment: please share your effort

Comment: First I tried with System.setProperty like:
                System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxy3.proxy.net");
  System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "3128");
That didn't work. Then I tried with Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command) where command is a shell command to set proxy.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't need to set any System-level properties. This is one way to do it in Firefox:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1); // Manual proxy config
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "proxy3.proxy.net");
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", 3128);
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.ssl", "proxy3.proxy.net");
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.ssl_port", 3128);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Or a more flexible, less browser-specific alternative:

```
org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("proxy3.proxy.net:3128");
proxy.setSslProxy("proxy3.proxy.net:3128");

DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();  // or chrome() etc.
caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(caps);
```

Comment: Did this help, OP?